# How do I make <textarea> recognize apostrophes as text only?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

Quite simply, the 'texarea' on my website is like texting, it allows users to enter text and it's posted onto the page.  I just found out that it treats the text as some sort of code, maybe SQL.

When I typed in **"Hello we're all fine"**, the apostrophe in the word "we're" had caused some confusion.

The error message displayed in the browser:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 're all set')' at line 1
```

Just in case you're wondering, here's the html :

```
<form action="comi.php" method="post">
        <textarea maxlength="227" type="text" name="input" cols="45" rows="4"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="POST" id="button" />
</form>
```

I thought that it may have something to do with the database, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry the first line should say : "Quite simply, the <textarea> on my website..."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I still don't get it, I thought thered be a simple solution

Comment: The solution is do not use any user input in without escaping in  SQL statements. This must be done on the server side since you cannot trust the client. See http://bobby-tables.com/. The problem is not only for SQL statements but for everything from the user. I recommend you learn about various kind of attacks like XSS, CSRF, SQL injection ... before starting any serious web development, otherwise your server and also the clients are at risk.

Comment: Ah, the little hitlers have decided that this is not a good question.  It seems to me (as others) that it is verifiable, does include enough information and the desired behaviour is obvious... Not to fail !!!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent SQL -injection you should use [Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE saveText
    @textArea nvarchar(50)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO myTable 
    (textArea)
VALUES
    (@textArea)
```

GO

This way, you will have no problems when you have a ' in your input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the string that you have typed so that the sql engine does not get confused.

```
$input = $_POST["textarea"];
$safe_input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
```

You need to use this in your sql statement.

**WARNING**

As others are trying to tell you, you are leaving yourself open to **sql injection** attacks.  Once you have the above working , you should read up on it.  There is a link in the comments above.

Answer (score -1):

$input = $_POST["textarea"];
$safe_input = addslashes($input);

Comment: No no no this is not going to protect anything